# What is this quadruple-dotted X above the staff?

Tags: notation, sheet-music

At the end of Shiro Sagisu's Robe Des Champs (KK_A09_miyagi), there is a dotted X with brackets covering two bars.

[image: Shiro Sagisu, KK_A09_Miyagi bar 33-37]

Comment: It matches the one shown [in this question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/44890/what-does-this-symbol-represent-x-with-four-dots) to be a variant of the double-sharp symbol... but that doesn't make sense to me in this context. Is it a part of the chord symbol, saying to add a twice-sharped second?

Comment: Where did you get this sheet music from?

Comment: I can't find a single YouTube recording that suggests what the symbol might mean. Most recordings are of the soundtrack version, which doesn't include the D.C. and excludes the two bracketed measures. The only recording I found that includes the D.C. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C5x8PaOZGXc) plays those two measures both times. The arrangement is by Makoto Kuriya, but I haven't found a recording by that musician, nor the sheet music.

Comment: The score is taken from "EVANGELION Piano Forte #1", the official piano transcription of music from the anime. There's an (illegal) scan on Internet Archive, which shows that symbol in many places, used as a footnote mark.

Comment: In general, ※ is the Japanese language equivalent of an asterisk: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_mark

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just look a bit further on the page: right below that staff there are two footnotes with the same symbol:

[image]

As the [comment from 小太郎](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/132933/what-is-this-quadruple-dotted-x-above-the-staff#comment249296_132933) explains, the `※` symbol is a [*reference mark*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_mark) used in Chinese, Japanese and Korean writing. This is clearly the case, since the published score was mainly intended for Japanese market.<sup>[1]</sup>

The second footnote can be translated as:

> These two measures are not played on the CD

It means that they probably existed in the original written score (and are probably played at some point in the anime), but they omitted them when recording the CD.

Here is the official recording, which doesn't include those two bars, exactly as the note indicates (the section starts around 1'08"):

It's an optional part that you may or may not play before returning to the beginning.
Whether you do it or not only depends your personal taste.

<sup>[1]: there is no absolute standard for reference symbols in music notation: for Western published music, the common one is the *asterisk*, but numbers or other symbols are also used (like ♦ or ♠), normally enclosed within square brackets (exactly like this note ;-) ); publishers may use their own standards, especially for cases involving complex annotations or multiple footnotes, which is common in *critical editions* (Barenreiter, Ricordi, etc.).</sup>

Answer (score -3):

It is a differently notated Segno sign. Various tradition in the notation and printing of music will have several different signs. Segno just means sign. Usually it is notated as follows, but hey printers can do what they like.

[image: Segno Sign]

Comment: Reading the accepted answer would make clear this is incorrect.

Comment: @Aaron right. It was a very good guess though without knowing it’s a Japanese score with Japanese asterisk. Might want to edit this to say “in general… but in this case see the answer by musicamante instead”?

Comment: @mirabilos The accepted answer was left long before and should have been read before posting. Also the symbol in question is nowhere in published music used as a segno (barring a counterexample). Finally, it makes no sense as a segno in this context, since there's a D.C. The D.S. would have to be at some earlier point in the piece, which would be very strange.

Comment: I seem to remember, from my initial research on this, at least one post somewhere on the net using that dotted X in place of the common symbol; the explanation was based on stylization: the circled ends of the "S" are the dots, and the curve is simplified to a line. Unfortunately I don't remember where I found it (and, frankly, I don't really want to repeat the research again). Besides, it doesn't make sense anyway here: the (smaller) "segno" in place of literal "D.S." is at the end of a section or sub-section, not somewhere before that; and the "2" next to it makes it even more inconsistent.